# How to copy the specific lines from file in python

Tags: python

I have a file which contains following lines.In this if i give the input string as "LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL" then it should copy the line from

```
6.959999999:    LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 
 0x0059005f, 
 0x0049006d, 
 0x00b9008b, 
 0x001300b9)
```

This is my file:

```
6.959999999:    LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 
 0x0059005f, 
 0x0049006d, 
 0x00b9008b, 
 0x001300b9)
7.959999999:    LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_Measure(1, 
 0x0059005m, 
 0x0049006d, 
 0x04b9008b, 
 0x001300b9)
```

My code:

```
fo=open("file1.txt","r")
fin=open("file2.txt","r")
string=raw_input("Enter the String:")
lines=fo.readlines()
   for line in lines:
       if string in line:
       fin.write(line)
fin.close()
```

Its copying only this much.

```
6.959999999:    LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0,
```

it's not copying until the end of close bracket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to read the file in chunks; your matching text only appears on one line, but to get the rest of the lines you'll have to continue reading:

```
with open("file1.txt","r") as fin, open("file2.txt","w") as fout:
    string = raw_input("Enter the String:")
    for line in fin:
        if string in line:
            fout.write(line)
            try: 
                while ')' not in line:
                    line = next(fin)
                    fout.write(line)
            except StopIteration:
                pass  # ran out of file to read
```

This uses the input file object as an iterable, looping directly over the open file object with `for line in fin`. Once a matching line is found, the nested `while` loop reads *more* lines from the same file object, until a line with `)` is found.

When the `for` loop then resumes after the `while` loop completed, the loop picks up where the file object has now progressed to.

Comment: @user3082400: Then you ran out of file before finding a line with `)` in it.

Comment: @user3082400: I added handling for that, but that does mean that you are perhaps dealing with a truncated input file.

Comment: I need one more help from u..can u see this link and solve the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650279/how-to-compare-lines-in-two-files-are-same-or-different-in-python?noredirect=1#comment30916463_20650279

Comment: I need one more help from u..can u see this link and solve the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660094/comparing-lines-of-two-text-files-in-python?noredirect=1#comment30931035_20660094

Comment: Please don't re-poke me; I had seen your earlier comment, just did not have time yet to look at your question.

Comment: please check the latest link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660094/comparing-lines-of-two-text-files-in-python if u have time.