# Comparing lines of two text files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two log files which contains following lines.I want to compare if data present is same or different in both of these files.

In this `file1.txt` data from `736.199070736:` to `0x000a00f5)` make it in a single line. 
It will come like this

```
736.199070736:  LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5).
```

And in `file2.txt` the first line is:

```
736.199047132:  LOG_TXBP_MOD_IF_RSP_DPCCH(BlockNum: 0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5)
```

So from the first line of both these files:
I want to compare the data From first line of `file1.txt`
    (0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5)

and the data From first line of `file2.txt`
    (BlockNum: 0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5)

I need to remove the `BlockNum:` text and then compare.

File1.txt which contains:

```
736.199070736:  LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 
 0x0075007f, 
 0x005500dd, 
 0x007f00d7, 
 0x0057005f, 
 0x00ff007d, 
 0x00f700dd, 
 0x00f50057, 
 0x000a00f5)
 736.209069960: LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 
 0x0075007b, 
 0x005500dd, 
 0x007f00d7, 
 0x0057005f, 
 0x00ff007d, 
 0x00f700dd, 
 0x00f50057, 
 0x000a00f1)
```

'file2.txt' contains:

```
736.199047132:  LOG_TXBP_MOD_IF_RSP_DPCCH(BlockNum: 0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5)
736.209044558:  LOG_TXBP_MOD_IF_RSP_DPCCH(BlockNum: 0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5)
```

My code is:

```
fin1=open("file1.txt","r")
fin2=open("file2.txt","r")
  for line1 in fin1:
      for line2 in fin2:
         if line==line2:
            print "same data"
         else:
            print "data are different"
```

This is not comparing properly what I want exactly.

Comment: Can you please format the question properly?

Comment: no dat is different and this is different.read the question properly

Comment: I gave you an answer in your [string processing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661416/how-to-print-specific-strings-in-python); you should really try and extrapolate from such answers. You appear to outsource each and every little problem to Stack Overflow answers, without any effort to learn a few new string methods yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your code is that compare the first line of file1 to all the lines in file2.

What you actually want to do is to read a line in file1, compare it to file2 if it is different reutun "different" and finish. Otherwise, finish comparing all the lines and return equal.

I don't like the answers in [how to compare lines in two files are same or different in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650279/how-to-compare-lines-in-two-files-are-same-or-different-in-python) since they load all the files in the memory.

What I would do is something like

```
f1 = open("file1")
f2 = open("file2")
line1 = next(f1)
line2 = next(f2)
found_different = False
while line1 and line2:
   if line1 != line2:
      found_different = True
      break
   line1 = next(f1)
   line2 = next(f2)

if not line1 and not line2 and not found_different:
   print "equal"
else:
   print "different"
```

Comment: no no.in file1 the data is  (0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5) and in file2 the data is (0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5).here i removed "BlockNum:".then i have to compare both these data

Comment: if u align my question u can understand this better

Comment: Oooh thanks for this. I'm comparing three text files (genomes) line-by-line and this is a much better solution than reading everything into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just read the files line by line but filter each line: extract the stuff within `(` `)` and remove `BlockNum:` if it exists. Something like this:

```
def getRecords(fn):
    for line in open(fn, 'r'):
        entry = line.rstrip()[line.find('(')+1:-1]
        if entry.startswith('BlockNum:'):
            yield entry[10:]
        else:
            yield entry

import itertools
filesAreEqual = all(a == b for a, b in itertools.izip(getRecords("file1.txt"),
                                                      getRecords("file2.txt")))
```

Comment: this is ok.but we can't hard code this script like if entry.startswith('BlockNum:'): and yield entry[10:-1].because that string will vary always.

Comment: @user3082400 You need to make your question more robust. Include context and uses in your script. Explain to us *how* the lines can change. Keep in mind that for every possible way your lines could be written, there could be *ten* ways to read it, each one helping you differently, and in ways that may not work across the board. So help us help you.

Comment: @user3082400 If the string `BlockNum` will vary, just skip everything up to (including) the `: `.

Comment: @ Frerich Raabe How to skip all texts before colon : ??

Comment: @user3082400 Just like my code skipped all characters before the `(`: `line[line.find(':')+1:]` yields the same string as `line` but without all the characters up to (and including) the first `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your second `for` loop, you say:

```
if line==line2:
```

When it needs to be:

```
if line1==line2:
```

Since it has no idea what `line` is, you get errors. Here is the corrected code, after testing.

```
fin1=open("file1.txt","r")
fin2=open("file2.txt","r")
for line1 in fin1:
    for line2 in fin2:
        if line1==line2:
            print "same data"
        else:
            print "data are different"
fin1.close()
fin2.close()
```

Happy coding!

Comment: no no.What i exactly want is in the first file take this data alone (0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5) and omit this text "736.199070736: LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL" and similar to this take the data from (BlockNum: 0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd, 0x007f00d7, 0x0057005f, 0x00ff007d, 0x00f700dd, 0x00f50057, 0x000a00f5).In this remove "BlockNum:" and then compare both of the datas??

Comment: Please be sure to read the StackOverflow markup system, so your posts look more presentable in the future.

Comment: @user3082400 When I edited your question, I removed some details. I just put them back, let me know if I fixed them correctly. In your latest edit those details are still gone, and I need to know that inside your code brackets, the text is reading exactly like the file.txt files are, because line formatting matters.