# How to print specific strings in python?

Tags: python

I have the follwing strings in a file:

```
736.199070736:  LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 
 0x0075007f, 
 0x005500dd,  
 0x000a00f5)
```

from these i want to take data from   "("  to  ")" and make it a single line.

Output should be in a single line like:

```
(0,  0x0075007f,  0x005500dd,   0x000a00f5)
```

Comment: Always add one line between `code` and text to make the formatting work.

Comment: Show us code where you try to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

string = """736.199070736:  LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 
 0x0075007f, 
 0x005500dd,  
 0x000a00f5)"""

result = re.search(r'\(.*\)', string) # matches anything between parenthesis

result.group()

'(0, 0x0075007f, 0x005500dd,  0x000a00f5)'
```

That gives you the data as a string.

Comment: Actually this is not a string.consider this data in a file(i meant line by line) .and join from "(" to ")" into a single line

Comment: It's between quotes, it's definitely a string. At the start of your post, you said, "I have the follwing strings in a file". Perhaps you didn't want a string, but that's what my code returns

Answer (score 2):

If you want it a single line:

```
''.join(''.join(text.splitlines()).partition('(')[1:])
```

Demo:

```
>>> text = '''\
... 736.199070736:  LOG_MOD_L0_RECEIVE_TXBRP_CONTROL(0, 
...  0x0075007f, 
...  0x005500dd,  
...  0x000a00f5)
... '''
>>> ''.join(''.join(text.splitlines()).partition('(')[1:])
'(0,  0x0075007f,  0x005500dd,   0x000a00f5)'
```

Bonus feature: If you pass this to `ast.literal_eval()` you get a Python structure with integers instead:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(''.join(''.join(text.splitlines()).partition('(')[1:]))
(0, 7667839, 5570781, 655605)
```